# Use of DapperExtensions to generate predicates with flagged enums

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper, dapper-extensions

I wish to generate a list of three predicates using DapperExtensions.Predicates class. I'm looking to achieve the generation of the following SQL's statement WHERE clause:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 
FROM A JOIN B ON A.Field1 = B.Field1 
WHERE ([B].[TypeProtectionInfoAdd] & 128 = 0) 
AND ([B].[TypeProtectionId] & 2049 = 2049) 
AND ([B].[TypeProtectionId] & 1024 = 0)
```

The fields TypeProtectionInfoAdd and TypeProtectionId are matched to values of flagged enums (ProtectionInfoAddEnum and ProtectionEnum) in the code.

I tried this:
I use the following method in the code to generate the predicates:

```
public string GetPredicateSql(IEnumerable<PlanDetails> planDetails)
{
var predicateGroup = new PredicateGroup
            {
                Predicates = new List<IPredicate>
                {
                    Predicates.Field<VIT9010_Plans>(x => x.TypeProtectionInfoAdd, Operator.Eq, planDetails.FirstOrDefault()?.VIT9010_Plans.TypeProtectionInfoAdd.Value & 128),
                    Predicates.Field<VIT9010_Plans>(x => x.TypeProtectionId, Operator.Eq, planDetails.FirstOrDefault()?.VIT9010_Plans.TypeProtectionId.Value & 2049),
                    Predicates.Field<VIT9010_Plans>(x => x.TypeProtectionId, Operator.Eq, planDetails.FirstOrDefault()?.VIT9010_Plans.TypeProtectionId.Value & 1024)
                },
                Operator = GroupOperator.And
            };
return GetSqlFromPredicate(predicateGroup);
}
```

I am expecting this:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 
FROM A JOIN B ON A.Field1 = B.Field1 
WHERE ([B].[TypeProtectionInfoAdd] & 128 = 0) 
AND ([B].[TypeProtectionId] & 2049 = 2049) 
AND ([B].[TypeProtectionId] & 1024 = 0)
```

When I run this query in SQL Server, I get the required result.

But I get this, which when run in SQL Server returns no result:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 
FROM A JOIN B ON A.Field1 = B.Field1 
WHERE ([B].[TypeProtectionInfoAdd] = 0) 
AND ([B].[TypeProtectionId] = 2049) 
AND ([B].[TypeProtectionId] = 0)
```

This is what makes me think that I need the predicates to be formatted correctly so I can get the equivalent SQL query. With this actual code, the query generated computes the bitwise operation and includes the result in the query directly (which is somewhat logical from what I wrote in the code). But I need to generate the SQL query with the WHERE clauses exactly as is in the preceding SQL query. Any idea, suggestions on how to format the predicates to get the correct result, please ?

Answer (score 1):

The code you were using was constructing the `&` on the client-side, not within the SQL.

It seems that DapperExtensions provides this built-in [using the `BitEq` operator](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/blob/ae7441406ce5eca803cedc0ab1f241b0ab460eaf/DapperExtensions/Predicate/FieldPredicate.cs#L99) (ie you don't need to construct the `&` as a separate `PredicateGroup`).

```cs
var predicateGroup = new PredicateGroup
{
    Predicates = new List<IPredicate>
    {
        Predicates.Field<VIT9010_Plans>(x => x.TypeProtectionInfoAdd, Operator.BitEq, 128, not: true),
        Predicates.Field<VIT9010_Plans>(x => x.TypeProtectionId, Operator.BitEq, 2049),
        Predicates.Field<VIT9010_Plans>(x => x.TypeProtectionId, Operator.BitEq, 1024, not: true)
    },
    Operator = GroupOperator.And
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But going through the "Operator" enum values, I can't see the BitEq appear. I'm I missing a specific library ?

Comment: Was added in this commit https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/commit/2989ad7cb2f241276ce688ed3e05b320fec4cb56 which seems to be dated after the last NuGet package from 2021-07-01. You might need to just download the whole project code and compile it yourself.

Comment: Working on an enterprise project, I can't take the initiative to download and compile the code without prior permission. I'll suggest this to the team and see how it goes.